# android studio does not show my theme right

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, preview

I have a problem when running android studio! It's not an error, rather an inconvenient.

I did some projects in the past and when I open them now, my theme in the preview looks different, even though when i did the project the preview looked fine.
Either my title bar is missing, or there is a mismatch between the colors i chose in my code vs. what is showing. Still, the theme changes in different ways from one app to another.
Here are some pictures with 2 of my projects (how the preview looks, vs how the app looks on the emulator and on the phone)

## [First app in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEm88.png)

## [First app on the emulator/also looks the same on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FylwZ.png)

## [Second app in the preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6J6M.png)

## [Second app on phone/emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REeGK.png)

I looked for several solutions on SO, and i tried a lot of options until now.
I reinstalled AS, i changed the App Theme to different themes, in the preview toolbar. At the beginning i had a rendering problem and i changed the Theme in the style file, writing Base. in front of it. This got rid of the rendering problem , but the theme did't look the same as on the device.
What can i do to make my theme look as it did in the beginning?

**this is the manifest for the first app**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.justjava">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**this is the manifest for the second app**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.miwok">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".NumbersActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_numbers" />
        <activity
            android:name=".PhrasesActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_phrases" />
        <activity
            android:name=".FamilyActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_family" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ColorsActivity"
            android:label="@string/category_colors">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**and this is the styles file for my first app**

```
<resources>


    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#D58F8E</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#A36965</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#A6D1B8</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#669884</item>

    </style>
    <style name="CustomCheckBoxStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/dp24</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/sp16</item>
    </style>
    <style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="CustomButtonStyle">
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/dp48</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/dp48</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: did you define app theme in Manifest file ?

Comment: post your manifest file code

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @HemantParmar no, i didn't change anything there, regarding the theme

Comment: OK so check first in Manifest file, app theme added or not.

Comment: @HemantParmar yes, it's added and i defined it in the styles file

Comment: does theme reflection is same device or different device ?

Comment: @HemantParmar i don’t know. Where can I check this?